# FAXCOMEXLib and Return Types

Tags: c#, com, activex, fax

I have an ActiveX control I built in VB 6.0 a long time ago to facilitate faxing and now I need to effectively translate this control into a C# class library.

I've added the reference to the FAXCOMEXLib library and Visual Studio has no problems seeing the objects, Properties, and Methods, but when I compile my DLL I run into two problems.
Firstly, the class library only seems to contain the properties and methods from FAXCOMEXLib that are actually used within my own library. This is a problem because I expose the COM objects through read-only properties.

```
public FaxServer   Server    {get { return m_Server;  }}
public FaxDocument Document  {get { return m_Document;}}
```

but if you call those properties and try to use the objects returned, you'll only have access to a limited number of methods and properties.

[FaxDocument has more than just ConnectedSubmit()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOV5e.png)

I thought that this could have been a compiler option that cut out code that wasn't used, but I can't find the option to turn it off.

---

My second problem is that the FaxServer.Connect() method returns an HRESULT [according to the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687537(v=vs.85).aspx), but Visual studio is treating it like a void return. I can't have this because I need to be able to check whether the connection was successful.

```
m_Server = new FaxServer();
if (m_Server.Connect("") == 0) // error CS0019 here
  throw new Exception("Could not connect to Server.");
```

Generates error CS0019 "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'void' and 'int'"

I don't know why it thinks that FaxServer.Connect() returns void.

[FaxServer in the Object Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQeSA.png)

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks,
Ken

Comment: You don't like the "Embed Interop Types" property of the reference.  Pretty unclear why since that should never be a problem, whatever code uses your library needs a reference as well and it will back-fill the missing properties.  But setting the property to No is pretty easy.  And you are trying to help too much, the Connect() method already throws an appropriate exception with a helpful localized descriptive message when it failed.  Substituting it with an "it did not work" message is not wise.

Comment: Ah, ok. I just recently learned about the Embed Interop Types option.  I'm OK with an exception handling solution, I just wanted to make sure that Connect() will throw exceptions when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

First VS will have generated a .NET wrapper from the ActiveX components type library (and then embedded that in the project's output). Rather than letting VS do that you can 1. use `Tlbimp.exe` to generate the .NET wrapper, 2. reference that wrapper in your project. See Importing a Type [Library as an Assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/importing-a-type-library-as-an-assembly).

Secondly non-success HRESULTs will be converted to exceptions, so you can detected failure with a `try…catch`.

(If you want to use `S_FAILED` and other success codes to distinguish levels of failure: you can't. Your only option to to create a COM wrapper in C++ that provides the success details in an `out` parameter. But you say the component is written in VB this case  won't apply.)